# Google play developer console asks me to remove a permission that does not even exist in the Mainefest

Tags: android, flutter

i got the following notification when i upload Flutter my app to Google console.

> We found that your manifest file contains the REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES permission.
> Starting September 29, 2022, apps that use this permission will not be able to submit >updates for review until they have completed a new sensitive permission declaration.
> This declaration will be available in Play Console on August 31, 2022. You'll need to >declare which permitted functionality your app provides, tell us about a core feature in >your app that uses the permission, and provide a video showing its use.
> You must remove this sensitive permission from your manifest if your app does not use >the permitted functionalities, or if you no longer use this permission. To learn more, >watch this PolicyBytes video.
> Permission description
> https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/12085295?hl=en

I checked the Mainefest. The permission is not declared there! How can i delete it!? It does not exist.

Comment: Check your merged AndroidManifest xml file, any of your third-party libraries might be using it.

Comment: i got the same issue as you, have you found a solution ? by the way in my case i checked the merged manifest and this permission does not exist in the third party libraries

Comment: @DaRkNight For me the solution was simple. I just had to go to app,json and set permissions to an empty array

    "android": {
      "package": "com.shareef.dweikat.alaqsamart",
      "googleServicesFile": "./google-services.json",
      "useNextNotificationsApi": true,
      "permissions": [],
      "versionCode": 12
    }

Answer (score 2):

Hello Shareef Dweikat,

It seems like you are using a 3rd library that's using this permission
It could be a Huawei SDK

Please double check inside the following path:
app/build/intermediates/merged_manifests

Comment: Yes it is Huawei SDK. How can i fix it?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using android studio try command + shift + f and type `REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES`. Select project from the top section. It will display all codes that use this key. Remove the package if its not being used.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys. I found a solation long time ago. Maybe somebody will benefit of it.
If you are using expo and encountering same problem, go to app.json and set permissions to []

```
"android": {
  "package": "com.shareef.dweikat.alaqsamart",
  "googleServicesFile": "./google-services.json",
  "useNextNotificationsApi": true,
  "permissions": [],
  "versionCode": 12
}
```